# How to process a CSV file from DB in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am a newbie to Django. While working on a project I have stuck on CSV operations and radio forms.
I have a file in my DB and it wants to read it in my views.py.
Below is the model using which I m uploading the file in the DB.

```
class Exam_Upload(models.Model):
Id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
Question_file=models.FileField(upload_to='Documents/')
```

where the CSV has the following columns:

```
Question Option1 Option2 Option3 Option4
```

I want all these fields to be displayed as- The question should be the ordered list in the HTML staring from 1 and the options should be in the radio button. Where I can save the selected option in the DB.

Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple csv reader like:

```
exam_obj = Exam_Upload.objects.get(id=1) #  use a specific ID or loop over all Exam_upload objects
csv_file = exam_obj
file_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
for row in file_reader:
    # do something with row data.
    print(row)
    # would print the rows like
    # Question, Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4
    # Question, Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.I m getting the below *error:file_reader=csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter=',')
TypeError: argument 1 must be an iterator*